# Change white gold to Yellow gold and vica verca, picture all black and white except jewelry and green and brown

Tags: gimp

First thing I guess I should say is I don't do graphics much at all... I've done a few decent little things (like my profile picture), but I'm still very well a beginner... I'm super duper broke so I can't afford for someone to do a mixtape cover... Unless I could find someone to do it for around like 50ish..
My Idea is for me and my girl to both wear our camo overalls.. I want to have everything black and white but on my side the tan/brown/gold in my pants, belt, boots and jewelry to show, & On her side the green and silver...
Also I have my 9 year old son and his favorite necklace of mine, and earrings from my 5 year old daughter... Anywho they're white gold & silver and I wanted to know if I could make them yellow gold to match my other ones??? And my girlfriend don't like yellow so I wanted to vica verca hers...
Is this something someone like me with very little experience could do??? Or do I need to come up with the money to pay someone with skills to do it???
Thank you in advance for the help and suggestions... This is very important not for me,my girlfriend (hopefully fiancé after a song on the mixtape and album),my son, and both my daughters, to finish something I started years ago and all of them have been encouraging me lately to complete it...

Comment: In theory you can make an area selection in a photo by using one of the numerous selection tools. Then you have numerous other tools to change the lightness, contrast and color of the selected area. Unfortunately nobody here knows what photos you actually have and do they offer a way to make the needed selections fast and would the same adjustment be good for several simultaneously selected areas. You should give an example. Do not waste your  time by showing screenshots where the interesting areas are only a few pixels wide each. This job needs high resolution images.

Answer (score 1):

Requests for free or paid work are off topic here.  I don't know your capabilities, but using GIMP is not rocket science.  If you have a basic understanding of how to make selections, create new layers, and make colour adjustments, then this is totally doable.

Here are the basics

1. Make a selection around the jewel using the lasso tool. Zoom in and make your selection as accurately as you can
2. Do *Edit > Copy*, then do *Edit > Paste as > New Layer*. Then do *Select > None*.

[image]

3. For changing white metal to gold, an easy way is to do *Colors > Color Temperature*, and move the Original Temperature slider to the left until it looks gold.

[image]

4. If there are diamonds or other gems, use a small soft edged eraser to erase away the top layer to reveal the original colour of the gems on the layer below.

[image]